# Segmentation fault with CR2 from kernel and RIP in userspace

Tags: linux, x86, segmentation-fault, kernel

I have a few segfaults with a similar state on Linux x86_64:

```
[pid 35742] [time 1699532462] signal caught:    Segmentation fault
si_signo:   11   
si_code:    SEGV_MAPERR
si_errno:   0
si_pid: 2166368523
si_uid: 4294967295
si_addr:    0xffffffff8120290b
si_status:  0
si_band:    0xffffffff8120290b
uc_flags:   0x1  
ss_sp:  0x7f7d25851000
ss_size:    1048576
ss_flags:   0x0  
REG_R8: 0xe76b5bc
REG_R9: 0x7f7d0743cc40
REG_R10:    0x7f7d0743b040
REG_R11:    0x0  
REG_R12:    0x0  
REG_R13:    0x0  
REG_R14:    0x7f7d25952020
REG_R15:    0x7f7d258137a8
REG_RDI:    0x7f7d258137a0
REG_RSI:    0x0  
REG_RBP:    0x7ffe5d6d86a0
REG_RBX:    0x7f7d258137a0
REG_RDX:    0x7f7c45f00000
REG_RAX:    0x0  
REG_RCX:    0x6  
REG_RSP:    0x7ffe5d6d8560
REG_RIP:    0x8af560
REG_EFL:    0x10242
REG_CSGSFS: 0x33 
REG_ERR:    0x15 
REG_TRAPNO: 0xe
REG_OLDMASK:    0xfffffffe00015a03
REG_CR2:    0xffffffff8120290b
```

While it seems to be a page fault with an attempt to execute kernel code I'm wondering how it can have RIP belonging to userspace.

Interestingly that the kernel code has jmp to the CR2 address just before a call instruction and userspace has a call instruction just before RIP.

The code near 0x8af560:

```
   0x00000000008af55b <+683>:   call   0x8adb50 <...>
   0x00000000008af560 <+688>:   mov    -0xe8(%rbp),%rdi
```

Comment: You aren't showing us the faulting user-space instruction at RIP=0x8af560.  Presumably it tries to access data at `0xffffffff8120290b` since that's the fault address.  The address is canonical so a jump or call to that address wouldn't fault before changing RIP, only after it attempts code-fetch from the new RIP (which the page tables should have mapped as kernel-only.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I added disasm. If it is mov - than REG_ERR shall not have X86_PF_INSTR set. Beside that rbp. rsp and rdi seem to be ok.

Comment: What does the function at `0x8adb50` do?  Could it have been `munmap()` of the page containing this instruction?  Or `mprotect` to make it non-executable?  That would explain a page-fault on instruction-fetch after return to a bad page. You're right, with that RBP value, `mov  -0xe8(%rbp),%rdi` wouldn't account for that CR2 fault address.  RDI is the destination which hasn't been written yet because the mov didn't execute.  (I'm guessing this is a non-PIE executable since the address doesn't start with `0x000055...`, so it will have the same address from run to run even with ASLR enabled.)

Comment: Err wait, no, return to a noexec or unmapped page wouldn't explain the CR2 fault address being a kernel address.  Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: You are right in your guess about non PIE. The function at 0x8adb50 is a kind of dispatcher for virtual function - so it may do anything, but for sure there is no malicious intent. My only guess is that it might be some kind of ret gadget or some bug in returning to userspace mixed with interrupts. Because accordingly to /proc/kallsyms 0xffffffff8120290b points to the correct and meaningfull for the server's workload function.